# How to use nginx load balancing with rethinkdb proxy?

Tags: nginx, proxy, rethinkdb

This question was indeed started as question and while doing research I came up with this setup for nginx balancing for multiple rethinkdb proxies.

I have 3 rethinkdb proxy servers running. For sake of discussion lets call them:

```
proxy0
proxy1
proxy2
```

then all of then connect(--join) to first db in rethinkdb cluster.
Now i i have defined nginx upstream like this:

```
upstream proxy {
    server proxy0:6003;      # rethindb proxy instance 0
    server proxy1:6003;      # rethinkdb proxy instance 1
    server proxy2:6003;      # rethinkdb proxy instance 2
}
```

and then just proxy pass that in `location /.`

This all looks great and simple but does not work.
I am getting python error like this:

```
File "isDead.py", line 86, in <module>
    o = DeadLinksDelete(db="db", db_host="loadBalancerAddress", api_url=url, page=sys.argv[2])
  File "isDead.py", line 22, in __init__
    password="pass")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rethinkdb/net.py", line 656, in connect
    return conn.reconnect(timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rethinkdb/net.py", line 567, in reconnect
    return self._instance.connect(timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rethinkdb/net.py", line 425, in connect
    self._socket = SocketWrapper(self, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rethinkdb/net.py", line 325, in __init__
    raise ReqlDriverError(error)
rethinkdb.errors.ReqlDriverError: Connection is closed.
```

Ok, my first problem is that I am assuming that rethinkdb driver connects to proxy via http/https and as from my example that assumption is wrong.

1. Install nginx from sources to support --with-sream like this:

> ./configure  --prefix=/opt/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx 
>   --conf-path=/opt/nginx/nginx.conf --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --with-threads --with-stream --with-http_slice_module --without-http_rewrite_module

2. Edit /opt/nginx/nginx.conf and add (after http{}):

> stream {
>
> server {
>       listen 6003;
>       proxy_pass db; }
>
> upstream db {
>       server proxy0:6003;
>       server proxy1:6003;
>       server proxy2:6003; }
>
> }

3. Start nginx with just `nginx`
4. Set db host in you app to your nginx load balancer and that is that.

This setup is now working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the drivers don't communicate over HTTP, you'd probably be better off using something like HAProxy which is designed primarily to proxy TCP connections.

Comment: hi, i have setup nginx tcp load balancer. but i will try HAProxy as well, since now i slowdown everything by 200ms.

Comment: xm, with haproxy page response went down to -300ms. thanks.